# Add Item Functionality In Opportunity customization Filtering Issue

Tags: acumatica

I have added a add item functionality like Sales Order in Opportunity. I have followed the same functionality of Sales Order.

The Add Item works fine, but the filtering on Inventory is not filtering the records. I have compared the aspx code and not able to figure out the issue

[image]

Comment: Only Inventory not working? did you check the Iscommitted is true for the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer the implementation of similar smart panel in SO301000 ASPX, it is performed via `FastFilterID` property of `PXGrid`.

[image]